# Event is undefined (javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I want to add an event manager but, it won't work?

Console shows me

```
"ReferenceError: event is not defined"
```

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].addEventListener("mousemove", myFunction(event));

function myFunction(event) {
    var x = event.pageX;
    var y = event.pageY;
    var coor = "Coordinates: (" + x + "," + y + ")";
    document.getElementByTagName('p')[0].textContent = coor;
}
```

```html
<div> 
<p></p>
</div>
```

Comment: That's not the error that you have.

Comment: I know that now, I can't put identifiers on my code. It's for school, they want us to target the elements using getElementsByTagName...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create an event listener, write the only name of the function:

```
element.addEventListener("mousemove", myFunction);
```

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].addEventListener("mousemove", myFunction);

function myFunction(event) {
    var x = event.pageX;
    var y = event.pageY;
    var coor = "Coordinates: (" + x + "," + y + ")";
    document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].textContent = coor;
}
```

```css
div {
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

While Vadim Shashkov is correct, there is more reasoning behind it. According to documentation put out by Mozilla (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) you are giving the `addEventListener` function a value instead of a function. You need to give it the function, which is why

```
document.getElementById('myDiv').addEventListener("mousemove", myFunction);
```

works.